# De serializing abstract classes in XML

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, abstract, xmlserializer

I have the following XML coming in from a web service request.

```
<Resource>
    <Create>
       <Name />
       <Reference />
       ...
    </Create>
</Resource>
```

However I can also have the following.

```
<Resource>
    <Delete>
       <Name />
       <Reference />
       ...
    </Delete>
</Resource>
```

I have a base class called operation as follows:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Create))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Delete))]
public abstract class Operation
{
    protected string Name {get; set;}
    protected string Reference {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

which both the class for Create and Delete inherit from and class called `Resource` which contains an `Operation` property.

```
public class Resource
{
    public Operation {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to deserialize the XML into the correct concrete implementation of the class `Operation`.

I have tried

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlData)))
{
    return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
}
```

where `T` is the type `Resource` but to no avail (`Operation` property is always `null`). Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

Might work if you design Operation as List. If you need to take measure that there will always be just one Operation for the User of the class then Hide this List Property to the normal user and publish a Operation Property also with [XmlIgnore] set.

Maybe XmlElement fits better to your need than XmlArrayItem.

```
public class Resource
{
    [XmlArrayItem("Create", typeof(Create))]
    [XmlArrayItem("Delete", typeof(Delete))]    
    public List<Operation> {get; set;}
}
```